# How can I get aws cloudwatch to fire alarm notifications repeatedly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

We have aws alarms set up to email on alarm but we would like to continue to get the alarm notification even if the state is in Alarm without a state change. How could I achieve this (would be happy to use a lambda but no idea how to do it)

Answer (score 1):

Amazon CloudWatch alarm notifications are only sent when the state of the alarm changes. It is **not possible** to configure CloudWatch to continually send notifications while in the `ALARM` state.

You would need to write your own code to send such notifications. This could be accomplished via a cron job, scheduled AWS Lambda function or your own application.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a script using Cloudwatch API for example with Boto3 + Python or a Lambda running every X minutes. I have a python script to get values from cloudwatch you can adapt it. http://www.dbigcloud.com/cloud-computing/230-integrando-metricas-de-aws-cloudwatch-en-zabbix.html

Answer (score 0):

One alternative is, to create a Lambda function to send email and host that function using CloudWatch Rule with Scheduled option and target as Lambda function that you have created. In Schedule option, you can set the frequency of time that you expect to receive email. In defined frequency, the Rule will trigger Lambda Function to send email.
[image]

Comment: I like this idea but, and correct if I am wrong, In this scenario will the lambda function not continue to execute even if the alarm goes back to an OK state? or would it be aborted?

Comment: No, logic is required to be written, that will not be automatic. The purpose of lambda function here in this case is to only send email.

Comment: This may be stupidly obvious but I'm not seeing how I can trigger a cloudwatch event from an alarm